# If multiple directories exist then move the directories - test if a globbing pattern matches anything

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob

I want to know how I can use an `if` statement in a shell script to check the existence of multiple directories.

For example, if `/tmp` has subdirectories `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, I want to move them to another directory.

I am using `if [ -d /tmp/test* ]; then mv test* /pathOfNewDir`
but it does not work on the `if` statement part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on one of the linux stack exchange sites.  Also not sure why it is tagged with css...

Comment: and what if the `/tmp` containing `/tmp/tsta`, `/tmp/tstb`, `/tmp/tstc`, `/tmp/ta`, `/tmp/tb`, `/tmp/tc` or `/tmp/a`, `/tmp/b`, `/tmp/c` ? e.g. what do you mean with "multiple directories"?

Comment: @Paddy: I don't think shell _programming_ is off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This approach uses `ls` and `grep` to create a list of matching directories or write an error in case no such directories are found:

```
IFS="
" # input is separated with newlines
if dirs=$( ls -1 -F | grep "^test.*/" | tr -d "/" )
then
  # directories found - move them:
  for d in $dirs
  do
    mv "$d" "$target_directory"/
  done
else
  # no directories found - send error
fi
```

While it would seem feasible to use `find` for such a task, `find` does not directly provide feedback on the number of matches as required by the OP according to the comments.

**Note:** Using `ls` for the task introduces a few limitations on filenames. This approach will not work with filenames containing newlines or wildcard characters.

Comment: Never ever parse off `ls`!

Comment: I know parsing `ls` is generally discouraged, but could you explain why you consider its use bad in this particular situation? Maybe it will help the OP and other readers more if we list the limitations of this approach like filenames with newline or wildcard characters in them.

Comment: @MichaelJaros: A matching directory name such as `test 1` (note the embedded space) would break your command, because the `for` loop would see that one name as _2_ tokens, `test` and `1`. `ls`'s output isn't designed for _parsing_ (programmatic consumption) - that's what pathname expansion (globbing) is for. Generally, you need _arrays_ to properly capture multiple tokens with embedded whitespace. In the case at hand, you could simply use `for d test*/;  do [[ -e $d ]] || break; mv "$d" "$target_directory"/; done` without the need for a separate test - see my answer for more.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into a better solution. I have added a modified `IFS` to additionally allow for spaces in filenames without modifying the accepted answer too much.

Comment: Thanks for the update; definitely an improvement (though still needlessly complicated); as an aside: in bash you could use `IFS=$'\n'` ([ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)), and it would help if you showed how to restore the original `$IFS` value. (If you want me to be notified of follow-up comments, you must include @mklement0.)

Answer (score 2):

The `-d` test only accepts one argument, so you'll need to test each directory individually.  I would also not recommend moving test* as it may match more than you intended.

Use the double-bracket syntax test syntax (e.g. `if [[ -d`...), which is bash-specific but tends to be clearer and have fewer gotchas than the single-bracket syntax.  If you just need to check a few directories, you can do it with a simple statement like `if [[ -d /tmp/test1 && -d /tmp/test2 && -d /tmp/test3 ]]; then`...

Comment: I am dealing with multiple directories.. not just 3.. so what if I have 100s of them starts with the name /test

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the **shell's file-testing operators (such as `-d` and `-f`) operate on a *single, literal* path only**:

- A conditional such as `[ -d /tmp/test* ]` won't work, because if `/tmp/test*` expands to *multiple* matches, you'll get a *syntax error* (only 1 argument accepted).
- The bash variant `[[ -d /tmp/test* ]]` doesn't work either, because no globbing (pathname expansion) is performed inside `[[ ... ]]`.

To **test whether a globbing pattern matches *anything***, the **cleanest approach is to define an auxiliary function** (this solution is POSIX-compliant):

```
exists() { [ -e "$1" ]; }
```

Invoke it with an [unquoted] pattern, e.g.:

```
exists foo* && echo 'HAVE MATCHES'

# or, in an `if` statement:
if exists foo*; then # ...
```

The only caveat is that if `shopt -s failglob` is in effect in bash, an error message will be printed to stderr if there's no match, and the rest of the command will not be executed.

See below for an explanation of the function.

---

Applied to **your specific scenario**, we get (using bash syntax):

```
# Define aux. function
exists() { [[ -e $1 ]]; }

exists /tmp/test*/ && mv /tmp/test*/ /path/to/new/dir
```

- Note the trailing `/` in `/tmp/test*/` to ensure that only *directories* match, if any.
- `&&` ensures that the following command is only executed if the function's exit code indicates true.
- `mv /tmp/test*/ ...` moves all matching directories at once to the new target directory.

---

Alternatively, capture globbing results in an helper *array* variable:

```
if matches=(/tmp/test*/) && [[ -e ${matches[0]} ]]; then
  mv "${matches[@]}" /path/to/new/dir
fi
```

---

Or, process matches individually:

```
for d in /tmp/test*/; do
   [[ -e $d ]] || break # exit, if no actual match
   # Process individual match.
   mv "$d" /path/to/new/dir
done
```

---

**Explanation** of auxiliary function `exists() { [ -e "$1" ]; }`:

It takes advantage of several shell features:

- If you invoke it with a[n unquoted] pattern such as `exists foo*`, the shell will expand `foo*` to all matching files/directories and pass their names *as individual arguments* to the function.
- If there are *no* matches, the pattern will be passed *as is* to the function - this behavior is mandated by POSIX.

  - Caveat: `bash` has configuration items that allow changing this behavior (shell options `failglob` and `nullglob`) - though *by default* it acts as mandated by POSIX in this case. (`zsh`, sadly, by default *fails* if there's no match.)
- Inside the function, it's sufficient to examine the *1st* argument (`$1`) to determine whether *any* matches were found:

  - If the 1st argument, `$1` refers to an actual, existing filesystem item (as indicated by the exit code of the `-e` file-test operator), the implication is that the pattern indeed matched something (at least *one*, possibly more items).
  - Otherwise, the implication is that the pattern was passed *as is*, implying that *no* matches were found.
  - Note that the exit code of the `-e` test - due to being the *last* command in the function - implicitly serves as the exit code of the function as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to use `find`:

```
find /tmp -name "test*" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv \{\} /target/directory \;
```

This finds all `test*` directories directly under `/tmp` without recursion and moves them to `/target/directory`.

Comment: thank you very much, however, I also want to send error message if the test directories does not exists on under the /tmp.. is there a way to do this using this?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately `find` does not provide information about its matches, and if its output is captured in a variable, there will be an extra newline that makes distinction of "no match" vs. "one match" unnecessarily complex. I have added another solution that allows sending an error message, but does not use `find`.

Comment: @MichaelJaros: More accurately, `find`'s _exit code_ doesn't reflect whether actual matches were found, only whether it was able to process the input paths specified. In this example, there's also no _output_, because the command invoked, `mv`, doesn't produce stdout output. Note that you can just use `{}` - no need for escaping, because `{`, and `}` have no special meaning to the shell. Also, in this case you could have used `-exec mv {} /target/directory +`  to make do with a _single_ invocation of `mv` using _all_ matching paths.

Comment: thanks for the hint on the `-exec [...] +` syntax, I didn't know that one

Comment: Addendum re "{, and } have no special meaning to the shell.": while `{` and `}` indeed have no special meaning to _POSIX-features-only shells_, they _potentially_ have special meaning to `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, and _always_ to `fish`.  These shells use expressions enclosed in `{` and `}` for so-called [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion), but in  `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` string `{}` is considered an _invalid_ brace expression and thus _passed through as is_, i.e., there's no _need_ to escape it (though it won't hurt).